# Add-on fire-fox auto call JavaScript after youtube comments loaded

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, firefox-addon

I'am trying to build add-on in fire fox browser. I use a page-mod so a script is triggered when landing on specific pages (Youtube), that can communicate the data to the main script. But it can't communicate with data comments because it loads after the page loaded ( using ajax or something ). Please help me!
my example:

main.js

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.youtube.com",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("jquery-1.8.3.js"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("element-getter.js"),
  contentScriptWhen: "end"          
});
```

element-getter.js

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    divs[i].setAttribute("style", "border: solid red 1px;");
}
```

you can see content of comments inside

`<div id = watch-discussion></div>`

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the contents are loaded after inital page load, you should use [MutatinObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) api. This will allow you to trigger a call back when contents of `watch-discussion` are modified.

Following is the snippet from one of my extensions:

```
// create an observer instance
var observer = new page.defaultView.MutationObserver(function(mutations, obs) {
  stopTube._handleMutation(mutations, obs);
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
// Here instead of page.body, you should be using page.getElementById('watch-discussion'), otherwise you will have too many notifications. 
observer.observe(page.body, config);         

page.addEventListener('unload', function(evt) {
  // remember to stop observing when you are done
  observer.disconnect();

});
```

Comment: I do not recommend to use mutation events. I had negative review experience for addon that uses such event for the same situation

Comment: do you have another ideal? I'm still can not apply it :(

Comment: I suggested to use setTimer. One of my extensions examines google search output using such way. It works with dynamic search mode very well

Answer (score 0):

use setTimer and check for comments DOM nodes in timer handler. Stop the timer once you completed comments processing.

Another way is to listen XMLHTTPRequests form the page and get comments from here